# Using Koala to post to a user's Page's wall from an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, permissions, koala

I already a facebook app with users already using it.  I already have the feature to post to their walls through Koala.

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new options[:fb_application_id], options[:fb_secret_key]
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new @oauth.get_app_access_token
@graph.put_connections(fb_user_id, "feed", :message => 'sample message')
```

Now I want to add a feature wherein I can get a user's Page ID and allow my app to post to that Page.

Something like below:

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new options[:fb_application_id], options[:fb_secret_key]
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new @oauth.get_app_access_token
@graph.put_connections 'the_page_id', 'feed', :message => 'this is a message to post'
```

The result of the line above is:

```
Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: OAuthException, code: 200, message: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action [HTTP 403]
```

I already set the permission 'manage_pages publish_actions publish_stream' in the app side and when the user authorized the app.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: I have same exact situation and same error received. Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: managed to fix this by updating the scope to ```manage_pages publish_pages publish_actions```

Answer (score 4):

The following might help,

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['KEY'], ENV['SECRET'], scope: 'manage_pages publish_pages publish_actions'
end
```

- `manage_pages` give you the access to the pages user manages
- `publish_pages` gives you the privilege to post as a page
- `publish_actions` gives you the privilege to post as the user

PS: `publish_stream` has been deprecated.

Comment: @koyz You're welcome! :-) If this helped, kindly mark the answer as the correct one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add publish_stream and publish_actions permissions to your app permission scope.

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to mention I also already did that. :) thanks! updated my post.